# Why does the Bootstrap grid stacks its columns in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following page which is displayed correctly with the `TOP BAR` taking the entire top space and the 3 other divs displaying next to each other below it.

However on `Chrome` it stacks everything on top of each other no matter what size the browser is. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Whatever</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            TOP BAR
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            I am left
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            I am center
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            I am right
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In order to reproduce this please link to the bootstrap files using the `integrity` constraint.

Comment: I can't recreate this. Columns are all aligned correctly in both browsers: http://www.bootply.com/mkzEpx8Ey5

Comment: It appears to be working just fine in [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaNpGq). Have you checked your browser console for errors, and ensured you don't have the page cached.

Comment: This isn't your issue, but you are missing jQuery which is a Bootstrap requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `Jdsfighter`'s comment after opening the `console` I saw the following errors:

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
>   resource
>   'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'
>   with computed SHA-256 integrity
>   '7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw='. The resource has been
>   blocked.
>
> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
>   resource
>   'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'
>   with computed SHA-256 integrity
>   'KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo='. The resource has been
>   blocked.

For some reason the integrity check did not work on my instance of `Chrome` and as the result I had to remove them.

Comment: It probably worked in browsers that don't implement the `integrity` attribute.

Comment: Yep, that would explain it.